# If multiple spans have different values, display alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of products (like a shopping cart) that is created by JavaScript/jQuery. In the list, all items have to belong to one main category.

For example, you can't have an item from INDUSTRIAL-A and INDUSTRIAL-B in the same list.

HTML example:

```html
<div id="{{divId}}" class="cart__row wishl-row" data-item="{{itemId}}" data-tags="{{product.tags}}">
    <div class="grid--full cart__row--table-large">
        <div class="grid__item large--three-fifths">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="grid__item one-third">
                    <a href="{{product.url}}?variant={{variant.id}}" title="{{product.title}}" class="cart__image">
                        <img src="{{featuredImage}}" alt="{{product.title}}" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="grid__item two-thirds">
                    <a href="{{product.url}}?variant={{variant.id}}" title="{{product.title}}" class="h4 cart__product-name">{{{product.title}}}</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span class="variant-option-key">{{this.name}}:</span> {{this.value}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <span class="variant-title">{{variantTitle}}</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span class="property-key">{{@key}}:</span> {{this}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__item large--two-fifths">
            <div class="grid--full cart__row--table">
                <div class="grid__item two-thirds text-center">
                    <p class="h4 cart__product-name">
                        <span class="categori" style="font-weight: 600;">{{ product.tags }}</span>
                        <br />
                        <span class="category">{{ product.tags }}</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="grid__item one-third text-right wishl-item-actions">
                    <a href="#" class="wishl-del" data-item="{{itemId}}" data-item-title="{{product.title}}">{{deleteLabel}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<span>` with the text that cannot be duplicated has the class attribute "categori". If every item in the list has INDUSTRIAL-A, then there is no `alert`. If there's the presence of INDUSTRIAL-A and INDUSTRIAL-B, then an `alert` is triggered.

Right now I have this code, but it yields an `alert` even when all items have INDUSTRIAL-A:

```js
var array = ["INDUSTRIAL-A", "INDUSTRIAL-B"];

$(array).ready(function () {

    // Using :contains()
    $("span.categori:contains(" + this + ")").ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("You have items from different category grades.");
        }, 1);
    });
});
```

I also tried this code:

```
var array = ["INDUSTRIAL-A", "INDUSTRIAL-B"];

$(array).ready(function () {

    // Using :filter()
    $("span.categori:filter(" + this + ")").ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("You have items from different category grades.");
        }, 1);
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get all the texts in span with id categori and push it to an array!
Following that you can check if all the elements are same or not returning true or false!!!

```
function checkForSameIndustry(){
    var span_text_array = [];
    $("span[id=categori]").each(function(index, elem){
        span_text_array.push($(this).text());
    });
    if(span_text_array.length > 0){
        return (!!span_text_array.reduce(function(a, b){ return (a === b) ? a : NaN; }));
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would something like this following example where you can iterate through each array item and check in your list selector. I hope I am driving you in right direction:

```js
$(function() {
  var array = ['INDUSTRIAL-A', 'INDUSTRIAL-B'];

  array.forEach(function(t) {
    $("span.categori:contains(" + t + ")").each(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert('You have items from different category grades.');
      }, 1);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="categori">INDUSTRIAL-A</span>
<span class="categori">INDUSTRIAL-C</span>
```